# Dealing with Error in Neural Network input

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

When you are building a neural network in which the input values are known to have error is there a way to incorporate this into the network? I.e one value of the input may have a known small error and so it's value is a good estimate; but another may have a larger standard error and so you are less confident in its true value.

Googling around this question is not easy because it's mostly Error Messages or error in the output that pops up so if someone here knows offhand that would be great thanks!

Comment: You may want to post this on Stack Exchange Data Science instead of Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to use some inverse of the error as a weight during training. Basically when you are calculating the loss of one input example during training you multiply it by its weight to. A higher weight leads to a higher loss and a higher impact on the gradient and the change of the wheights.

By choosing for example `1 / standard error` as the weight, a false estimation of an input with high uncertainty is not weighted as much as a certain example.